# What maven dependecy do I need to support org.zkoss.reference.developer?

Tags: maven, zk

What maven dependency do I need to configure to support the following package :

```
org.zkoss.reference.developer
```

Answer (score 0):

In maven world you may find the answer by querying the repositories, such as

[[http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav]](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav%5d)

Usually gives quite a few hits, but you need a classname

Comment: I found that ZK offers some archetype for a ZK project, maybe that would be helpful: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/